# PHP 7 regex not working the same way as in 5

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

So I have to use php 7 and I have the following regex which works just fine in 5.5 and 5.6.

```
([\\'\\\"].*[\\'\\\"])([\\s]*[\\s]*=>[\\s]*[\\s])(\\[([^\\[\\]]|(?R))*[\\s]*[\\s]\\])/m
```

when I run this in any version of 5 with preg_match_all I get the correct result. Basically I am trying to match an array in a text file of the form

```
'key' => [
   'val1 => 'sdsd',
   'val2' => '3e3',  
]
```

The above expression selects this array. In PHP 7 (7.0.8 and 7.0.9) returns no matches what so ever.

Anyone has any ideas as to why and better yet how do we port expressions to 7?

Edit :

The code used

[can be found in this gist](https://gist.github.com/mbouclas/65352a2ff4462cd2ef96b3b41a90453f)

What is weird, is that it does work on some versions of php 7. For example, my VM is running

```
PHP 7.0.9-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1 (cli) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
with Zend OPcache v7.0.9-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1, Copyright (c) 1999-2016,        by Zend Technologies
```

and it works fine, the production server on the other hand, runs

```
PHP 7.0.9 (cli) (built: Jul 22 2016 11:36:32) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
with Zend OPcache v7.0.9, Copyright (c) 1999-2016, by Zend Technologies
```

and it doesn't work at all. $matches is always empty no matter what. Same thing on another ubuntu desktop i'm using. It also doesn't work on windows using

```
PHP 7.0.9 (cli) (built: Jul 20 2016 10:47:41) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
```

It works on all machines using various 5.x versions

Comment: 3 backslashes in a row?

Comment: FYI: You do not need to escape `'` nor `"` for the regex engine, only escape once for the PHP engine.

Comment: Working [php7](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/478b97cae9becd939c95ffb685358e8ad3fabe07) *and* [php5](http://ideone.com/iekyDI). Could you share your code?

Comment: @ThomasAyoub It behaves the same way as mine does. If you check my edited question i have a list of php versions that it doesn't work on. Same happens with yours. It worked on the VM but production and windows is no joy, it comes back empty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've got it to work with this regex (matches are the same than in your requirement):

```
$matchArray = '~([\'"][^\'"]*[\'"])(\s*=>\s+)(\[(?:[^\[\]])*\s+\])~m';
```

instead of yours:

```
$matchArray = '~([\'"].*[\'"])([\s]*[\s]*=>[\s]*[\s])(\[([^\[\]]|(?R))*[\s]*[\s]\])~m';
```

See [buggy version](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/4dd99fb2992a49a5b217b788bb9bff13971b5d77) and [working version](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/4025900128b6e9d59478ee60f869e6a5e5428c7f).

I *would* say that it's due to some timeout changes but I can't find any reverent information about that.

Comment: Yeah, this works fine. I came up with a similar solution just now but it didn't work on the windows version of PHP. It'd be interesting to find out what's up with that though. Thanks for the help